# The RelayCommand for enable/disable a button don't work like expected

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.6.2

The case is that I try to disable a button in the window form when it was clicked and after some time (some seconds) it should be enabled again.

But this didn't work. After a click on the button the command set the enabled to `false` and after some seconds the command set it back to `true` (I tested it, the order is right and it set it to `true` again) but the button is still not enabled on the window form.

For that case I use a `RelayCommmand`. The `RelayCommand` is a standard class you find on Internet and will be shown in the end. 
To organise the command I wrote a class called `Testclass`:

```
class Testclass
{
    private bool _testValueCanExecute;
    public bool TestValueCanExecute
    {
        get { return _testValueCanExecute; }
        set
        {
            _testValueCanExecute = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand TestValueCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Testclass()
    {
        TestValueCommand = new RelayCommand(TestMethod, param => _testValueCanExecute);
        TestValueCanExecute = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private async void TestMethod(object obj)
    {
        TestValueCanExecute = false;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        TestValueCanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

In the XAML File I added a button as followed:

```
<Button x:Name="TestButton" Command="{Binding TestValueCommand}" Content="Test Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

The `MainWindow` code looks as followed:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Testclass();
    }
}
```

So the `RelayCommand` use the `TestMethod` method set the command enable variable to `false`, wait 3 seconds and set them back to `true`. But as I wrote above the button on the window form still not enabled.

It would be nice to understand what happens here and how I can solve this.

*Update:*
I use the following Code for the `RelayCommand`:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I may need more caffine, but this code seems confusing - such as your setter OnPropertyChanged(); doesnt list which property you're changing so to me it would seem its right nothing would change

Comment: @BugFinder the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute makes sure to send the name behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks @Default I just dont see how it knows its supposed to enable/disable..

Comment: @BugFinder oh. Sorry, I guess I misunderstood. In that regard I agree with you, but I believe that is a misunderstanding from the OP, because he never does trigger enable/disable of the command. It _shouldn't_ (depending on the implementation of RelayCommand) have anything to do with the OPC method though.

Comment: Your implementation doesn't have any RaiseCanExecuteChanged() method. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The `RelayCommand` is a standard class you find on Internet ...

There is no such thing as a "standard class you find on Internet". In fact there are several different implementations of the `RelayCommand` available "on the Internet".

A good implementation should contain a method for raising the `CanExecuteChanged` event. MvvmLight's implementation has a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method that does this. You need to call this one to "refresh" the status of the command:

```
private async void TestMethod(object obj)
{
    RelayCommand cmd = TestValueCommand as RelayCommand;
    TestValueCanExecute = false;
    cmd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    TestValueCanExecute = true;
    cmd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

The event is *not* raised automatically when you set the `TestValueCanExecute` property and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the view model.

**Edit:** Your implementation doesn't have any `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method. Add one to your `RelayCommand` class and call it as per above:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To use a framework is one possible answer, but at the moment I try to get into C# and for that I want understand what happens and to learn how it works. For that it would be nice to see how a simple `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` can be written by my own. And expectedly I hope to understand how it works and why the code from me don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using existing frameworks, instead of inveting the wheel once again. 
Take a look at [ReactiveUI ReactiveCommand](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/an-example)

In your case, it would do all the work by itself:

```
TestValueCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await Task.Delay(500));
```

You bind that command to a button in xaml and the button is disabled until command is done.

You can easily add another condition for disabling the command, and then, binding will disable button